# How to get all the same views type in the layout?

Tags: android

Is there function in android like `getByType()`?

How can we collect all the views with the same type (like all the checkbox)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out it will surly help you :

```
if (view instanceof EditText) {
EditText editText = (EditText) view;
// do what you want with EditText
}
else if (view instanceof TextView) {
TextView textView = (TextView) view;
// do what you want with textView
}
 else if ..
```

Comment: Thanks,
I understand that there is no choice and i must use this long way

Comment: @rivto upvote if it help you and let me know if still stuck